# Get the sum of surrounding elements in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

In a `[N][N] Matrix`, what would be the best way of obtaining the sum of the 8 elements surrounding a certain element?

We've been doing it the brute way, just checking with a lot of `if` statements but i was wondering if there could be a most *clever* way of doing this.

The problems we face are the borders of the matrix, since we cannot find a way that looks more subtle than the original bunch of `if(i>0 && j>0){...}`

Comment: If the neighbours can wrap to the other edge, use a modulus operator, but be careful when < 0 where you should add the width/depth before taking the modulus, such as `(i - 1 + N) % N`.

Comment: No, in my case, the Matrix represents the 'brightness' of lights in a plane, so they do not wrap.

Comment: Another way could be make the matrix 2 elements bigger in each dimension, then the elements are indexed `1..N` and if the matrix (borders) is initialised to `0` then there is no edge overflow, and a benign `0` is added to the neighbour sum.

Comment: ... but that might distort your calculations, is you want to, say, calculate an average of the neighbours. Yet another suggestion is to run one double-loop for the interior, four linear loops for the edges (if the matrix is square then a single loop looking at each edge), and finally treat the 4 corners.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the matrix has been initialized and you are considering calculating sums of those elements whose all eight counterparts exist.Then you can save your time if you apply double for loops for only those elements by doing the following :

```
Let a N x N matrix then use the following to cover all the elements satisfying the above conditions


  for( i =  1; i < N - 1 ;i++)
    {
      for( j = 1;j < N -1 ;j++)
      {
        //YOUR CODE 
      }
    }
```

Comment: That is the standard way to loop over an entire matrix, but the problem is not that, its about getting the surrounding elements, checking if they 'exist' first